# if metabox is empty, button hide

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want the button hide when it is empty remain unfortunately only the HTML before, even though the button is already empty, how can I rewrite the code so the button is hidden?

```
function cspm_infobox_content(){
        $telnr = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'telnr', true );

        $email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', true );

  .........
 elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type5'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="telnr"><a class="wm-button color-read" href="tel:'.$telnr.'"><img src="Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';
                                                $output .= '<a class="wm-button color-blue email" href="mailto:'.$email.'"><img src="email-ico.png" height="18" width="18"></a></div>';
```

Comment: ... don't understand your question. try it once again and better. What is empty? What is hidden button (in your code is no button, hidden means that it isn't in HTML, or is hidden by CSS, ...?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand  your question correctly .
Can you provide the detail code.

I think you should use

```
if($infobox_type!= ''){

// show th button .
}
```